# angularjs2 and ionic2 while parsing file

Tags: angular, ionic2

[image]

While parsing `file`
this is line  public http:Http;

Comment: Include the code snippet in the question and not just an image of it!!

Comment: Your image of text isn't very helpful.  It can't be copied
into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, making other
users with the same problem less likely to find the answer
here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant
text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid
transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas your question is a bit short, I think that your problem is that you try to use types in method parameters whereas you use ES6 and not TypeScript.

Method parameters are only supported in TypeScript.

There are two solutions to fix your problem:

- With ES6, use the static `parameters` getter to configure the expected types for dependency injection:

  ```
  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
  ```
- You create your Ionic2 project with the `--ts` option with `ionic start`.